# USB hub on Sonoma disconnects mouse after sleep

Tags: usb, sleep-wake, mouse, sonoma

I have a usb hub with a usb mouse attached to the hub.  MacOS 14.2.1 on MacbookPro 2018.

Everytime I wake my computer from sleep (1 min or sleep or overnight) the attached mouse doesn't work and I need to pull the lead out and reattach it.

Any ideas of how to tell my MacOS to keep the mouse connected?